# Can an RCD detect a fault on an isolated circuit?

Tags: short-circuit, home-installation, rcd

I was installing a new plug socket today in an outbuilding of my house, which is wired up to a small circuit breaker box which houses breakers for the lights and plug sockets in this outbuilding. This smaller circuit breaker box is then presumably wired up to the houses main circuit breaker box, which houses an RCD along with all the breakers for the rest of the house.

Before working on the sockets in the outbuilding, I turned off the plug sockets and light circuit breakers to the outbuilding on this smaller circuit breaker box, yet, when I began to work on the socket and stripped the wires, it caused the RCD in the main circuit breaker box to trip, cutting power to the whole house.

How is this possible? I thought that by cutting power to the outbuilding, the RCD wouldn't be able to "see" that part of the circuit?

Comment: The breakers generally only disconnect the live feed and not the neutral. It's possible to get enough current flowing from neutral to earth to trip an RCD.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you. Where would this current come from? Is the static in my body enough to trip the RCD?

Comment: No, that would never generate enough current. It's most likely the slight difference between neutral and earth generated by current flowing through the resistance of the neutral wire.

Comment: Where would this current in the neutral wire come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single-phase circuit-breaker will only *disconnect* the live. It can't fully *isolate* if the neutral is still connected.

Neutral is bonded to earth / ground at the distribution transformer or at the service entrance to the property. If there is any electrical load running in the property there will be current flowing in the neutral. Since the neutral has resistance we can predict that there will be a voltage (V = IR) on the neutral wire. (This might only be a couple of volts.) Generally, the further you go from the earth bonding point, the higher this neutral-earth voltage will be.

Now if you ground the neutral some current will flow. The RCD will sense that there is an imbalance between what's going out on the live and what's returning on the neutral (they don't cancel out anymore) and will disconnect the supply to ensure your safety.

> Ah I see, thank you - how come electrical loads cause current to flow in the neutral? My knowledge is basic but I always presumed earth meant any current that went into it is immediately dissipated into wherever the earth terminates.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvJR3u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. LAMP2 has been removed and the neutral accidentally connected to earth.*

It's a circuit. Current that comes in on the live must return to the source via the neutral. If it didn't then why would we need neutral wiring or why couldn't we use a much lighter wire for the neutral? Earth fault currents do dissipate through the ground but must "un-dissipate" back at the transformer's earth-neutral connection. What goes out on L must come back on neutral and/or earth.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you - how come electrical loads cause current to flow in the neutral? My knowledge is basic but I always presumed earth meant any current that went into it is immediately dissipated into wherever the earth terminates.

Comment: See the update.